# How to cache or pre-render canvas animation

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, html5-video, requestanimationframe

I am in the process of doing some slight modification (color keying) to an inline html5 video using canvas. Now, this video is a loop and I'm thinking there are more optimal ways then having a looping video being evaluated and repainted every single time. What optimizations if any can I do to either a) pre-render the entire animation or b) cache the original loop so that no more processing/evaluation needs to occur. I find that I'm being totally inefficient in CPU / memory usage by constantly letting it run.

I am currently using the following code (note, im using Vue.js, so assume that all the current function and variable assignments work correctly already) :

```html
loadVideo() {
 
 this.video = document.getElementById('globe');
 this.c1 = document.getElementById("c1");
 this.ctx1 = this.c1.getContext("2d");
 let that = this;
 
 this.video.addEventListener("play", function() {
  that.vWidth = that.video.videoWidth / 2;
  that.vHeight = that.video.videoHeight / 2;
  that.fpsInterval = 1000 / 120;
  that.then = Date.now();
  that.startTime = that.then;
  that.computeFrame();
 }, false);
 
}

computeFrame() {
 
 requestAnimationFrame(this.computeFrame);
 this.now = Date.now();
 this.elapsed = this.now - this.then;
 
 if (this.elapsed > this.fpsInterval) {
  this.ctx1.canvas.width = this.video.offsetWidth;
  this.ctx1.canvas.height = this.video.offsetHeight;
  if (this.video.offsetWidth > 0 && this.video.offsetHeight > 0) {
   this.then = this.now - (this.elapsed % this.fpsInterval);
   this.ctx1.drawImage(this.video, 0, 0, this.ctx1.canvas.width, this.ctx1.canvas.height);
   let frame = this.ctx1.getImageData(0, 0, this.ctx1.canvas.width, this.ctx1.canvas.height);
   let l = frame.data.length / 4;
   let primaryColor = this.ctx1.getImageData(0, 0, 8, 8).data;
   let primaryR = primaryColor[60];
   let primaryG = primaryColor[61];
   let primaryB = primaryColor[62];
   for (let i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    let r = frame.data[i * 4 + 0];
    let g = frame.data[i * 4 + 1];
    let b = frame.data[i * 4 + 2];
    if (r == primaryR && g == primaryG && b == primaryB) {
     frame.data[i * 4 + 1] = 255;
     frame.data[i * 4 + 2] = 0;
     frame.data[i * 4 + 3] = 0;
    }
   }
   this.ctx1.putImageData(frame, 0, 0);
  }
 }
 
}

loadVideo();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) to record the video stream returned by your cavnas [`captureStream()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/captureStream) method to record the first pass, and then read the resulting recorded video directly in a looping <video>:

```js
btn.onclick = e => {
  // initialise the <video>
  const vid = document.createElement('video');
  vid.muted = true;
  vid.crossOrigin = true;
  vid.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/transcoded/a/a4/BBH_gravitational_lensing_of_gw150914.webm/BBH_gravitational_lensing_of_gw150914.webm.480p.webm";
  vid.playbackRate = 2;
  vid.onplaying = startProcessing;
  vid.play();
  btn.remove();
  log.textContent = 'fetching';
};

function startProcessing(evt) {
  // when video is playing
  const vid = evt.target;
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  canvas.width = vid.videoWidth;
  canvas.height = vid.videoHeight;
  // show the canvas for first round
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  // force first frame
  anim();
  
  const chunks = [];   // we'll store our recorder's data here
  const canvasStream = canvas.captureStream();
  const vp = 'video/webm; codecs="vp',
    vp8 = vp + '8"',
    vp9 = vp + '9"';
  const recorder = new MediaRecorder(canvasStream, {
    mimeType: MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported(vp9) ? vp9:vp8,
    videoBitsPerSeconds: 5000000
  });
  // every time new data is available
  recorder.ondataavailable = evt => chunks.push(evt.data);
  // record until the video ends
  vid.onended = evt => {
    recorder.stop();
  };
  recorder.onstop = exportVid;

  recorder.start();
  log.textContent = "recording";
  
  function anim() {
    if(vid.paused) {
      console.log('stop drawing');
      return;
    }
    ctx.drawImage(vid, 0, 0);
    applyFilter(ctx);
    requestAnimationFrame(anim);
  }
  
  function exportVid() {
    // concatenate all our chunks in a single Blob
    const blob = new Blob(chunks);
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    // we reuse the same <video> (for Safari autoplay)
    vid.onplaying = vid.onended = null;
    vid.src = url;
    vid.loop = true;
    vid.playbackRate = 1;
    log.textContent = "playing";

vid.play().then(()=> canvas.replaceWith(vid));
  }
}


function applyFilter(ctx) {
  const img = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  const data = new Uint32Array(img.data.buffer);
  for(let i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    if(data[i] < 0xFF111111) data[i] = ((Math.random()*0xFFFFFF) + 0xFF000000 | 0);
  }
  ctx.putImageData(img, 0, 0);
}
```

```css
canvas,video{
  max-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">start</button><pre id="log"></pre>
```